# Write a alert condition for Application monitoring using NewRelic Agent?

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform, synthetic, nrql, newrelic-synthetics

I recently installed the New Relic agent on Windows server 2012. The goal I am trying to achieve is to create the alert condition for IIS application pools running in windows server 2012 using New Relic Agent when the application is stopped need to get the Message or mail immediately.

To Achieve this goal I have installed the New Relic agent in the windows server 2012 and retrieved the data to the New Relic.

I am stuck on how to create the Alert conditions for the IIS application pool when the Application is stopped and need to get the alert messages immediately.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking to create an alert that will tell you when your application stops. There are a couple of suggestions related to your request that may help you out here:

https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/monitoring-iis/115852/3